# Convert bytes to a file object in python

Tags: python, string, file, bytestream

I have a small application that reads local files using:
`open(diefile_path, 'r') as csv_file`
`open(diefile_path, 'r') as file`
`and also uses linecache module`

I need to expand the use to files that send from a remote server.
The content that is received by the server type is bytes.

I couldn't find a lot of information about handling IOBytes type and I was wondering if there is a way that I can convert the bytes chunk to a file-like object.
My goal is to use the API is specified above (`open`,`linecache`)
I was able to convert the bytes into a string using `data.decode("utf-8")`, 
but I can't use the methods above (`open` and `linecache`)

a small example to illustrate

```
data = 'b'First line\nSecond line\nThird line\n'

with open(data) as file:
    line = file.readline()
    print(line)
```

output:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

`open` is used to open actual files, returning a file-like object. Here, you already have the data in memory, not in a file, so you can instantiate the file-like object directly.

```
import io


data = b'First line\nSecond line\nThird line\n'
file = io.StringIO(data.decode())
for line in file:
    print(line.strip())
```

However, if what you are getting is really just a newline-separated string, you can simply split it into a list directly.

```
lines = data.decode().strip().split('\n')
```

The main difference is that the `StringIO` version is slightly lazier; it has a smaller memory foot print compared to the list, as it splits strings off as requested by the iterator.

Comment: thank you, so from what I understand, I will have to change the API to something else than 'open'

Answer (score 5):

The answer above that using `StringIO` would need to specify an encoding, which may cause wrong conversion.

from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=bytes%20file#binary-i-o) using `BytesIO`:

```py
from io import BytesIO
f = BytesIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")
```